# Solve system of equations $ y + 3x = 4x^3$ and $x + 3y = 4y^3$

Tags: systems-of-equations, cubics, symmetric-polynomials

Problem: In the set of real numbers find all $x,y$ that satisfy
$ y + 3x = 4x^3,x + 3y = 4y^3$.

What I don't understand, is how do I know that a condition satisfies both equations(I will show later exactly).

The solution goes like this: By addition and substraction of the equations we get the following 2 equations:
$x + y = (x + y)(x^2 − xy + y^2),x − y = 2(x − y)(x^2 + xy + y^2)$.
My question is, how do I know which conditions have to be true? According to the solution either $x+y=0$ or $x-y=0$, which I understand. My problem comes when they mention that both $(x^2 + xy + y^2)=1/2$ and $(x^2 - xy + y^2)=1$ have to be true at the same time. Why both? How do systems of equations work and how do we know that there won't be another solution if we multiply or divide the equations? Any tips for these kinds of problems are greatly appreciated.

Question 2: Why can't we also try to find a solution which satisfies for example $x-y=0$ and $(x^2 − xy + y^2)=1$

Comment: The relations you mentioned,  they do not have to be true at the same time.  For example if $(z-1)(z-2)=0$ , then it does not mean that $z=1$ and $z=2$ ...but one or the other.

Comment: That implies that the if either of the new equations is true than the original system of equations is true as well? And another note, they still solved it by using $(x^2+xy+y^2)=1/2$ and $(x^2−xy+y^2)=1$ at the same time. Why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a natural way to solve the system. Continue with,

$$x + y = (x + y)(x^2 − xy + y^2),\>\>\>\>\>
x − y = 2(x − y)(x^2 + xy + y^2)$$

or,

$$(x + y)(x^2 − xy + y^2-1)=(x − y)(x^2 + xy + y^2-\frac12)=0$$

So, there are four cases to be considered,

Case 1: Substitute $x-y=0$ into one of the original equations, say, $y + 3x = 4x^3$, which leads to,

$$4x(x^2-1)=0\implies x= 0, \pm 1$$

Case 2:  Similarly, $x+y=0$ leads to,

$$2x(2x^2-1)=0\implies x = 0,\pm \frac 1{\sqrt2}$$

Case 3: Substitute $x^2 − xy + y^2-1=0$ into $y+3x=4x^3$, leading to

$$16x^6-28x^4+13x^2-1=0,\>\> \text{or}$$

$$(x^2-1)(16x^4-12x^2+1)=0\implies x=\pm 1,\pm\frac{\sqrt5\pm 1}{4}$$

Case 4: Similarly $x^2 + xy + y^2-\frac12=0$ leads to

$$(2x^2-1)(16x^4-12x^2+1)=0\implies x=\pm \frac1{\sqrt2},\pm\frac{\sqrt5\pm 1}{4}$$

Thus, all the real solutions are:

$(0,0), (1,1), (-1,-1),
(\frac 1{\sqrt2},-\frac 1{\sqrt2}), (-\frac 1{\sqrt2},\frac 1{\sqrt2}), $
$(\frac {\sqrt5 + 1}{4},\frac {-\sqrt5 + 1}{4}), (\frac {\sqrt5 - 1}{4},\frac {-\sqrt5 - 1}{4}), 
(\frac {-\sqrt5 + 1}{4},\frac {\sqrt5 + 1}{4}), (\frac {-\sqrt5 - 1}{4},\frac {\sqrt5 - 1}{4})$

Note that the system of the two equations are implicitly of ninth order. So, it is expected to have nine pairs of solutions.

Comment: The problem is, that there are more solutions. Such as $(1/4+√5/4,1/4−√5/4)$

Comment: @AdamPedrovec - Now, the solutions are complete.

Answer (score 1):

If $$a\cdot b =a\cdot b'$$ and $$c\cdot d=c\cdot d'$$ then if $a\neq 0 $ and $c\neq 0$ then $b=b'$ and $d=d'$.

---

For the second question, if $m\cdot n =0$ then we now only $m=0$ or $n=0$. It is not necessary both are $0$.

Comment: In my case, the solution doesn't mention $a=0$ and $d=d'$. Why is that?

Comment: Oh okay, now I get it. Thanks for your help

Comment: Another question if I may. The solution suggests that $a=0$ or $c=0$ is enough, and not both of two new equations have to be satisfied. But at the longer equations both of them have to be true at the same time. Why is that?

Comment: Write $2xy= (x^2 + xy + y^2)-(x^2 - xy + y^2)=-1/2$ so $y=-1/(4x)$ and plug in to one of them. You get, probably, a quadratic equation with no real solution.

Comment: And why isn't just $(x^2−xy+y^2)=1$ enough, why do we use the other one too? Clearly $x=y$ satisfies only the second equation, but not the first, yet it still is a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Hint.

We have with $f(x) = 4x^3-3 x$

$$
y = f(x)\\
x = f(y)\\
$$

or

$$
y = f^2(y)\\
x = f^2(x)
$$

so the solutions are the fixed points

[image]

which are

$$
\left\{0,\pm 1, \pm\frac{\sqrt 2}{2},\frac 14\left(-1\pm\sqrt 5\right),\frac 14\left(1\pm\sqrt 5\right)\right\}
$$

NOTE

$$
f^2(x)-x = f(f(x)) -x = 8 (x-1) x (x+1) \left(2 x^2-1\right) \left(4 x^2-2 x-1\right) \left(4 x^2+2 x-1\right)
$$